# Does XeLaTeX automatically select optical sizes for a given font, if available?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontsize, optical-size

I've been intrigued by a great feature of XeLaTeX (perhaps it was already a feature of (La)TeX) for a long time -- its ability to automatically select the appropriate optical size of a font for a specific part of the text.

At least it seems to me -- when I open a PDF in Adobe Reader, it shows caption, display, regular, even semibold, etc.

So far I haven't come across a clear mention of it, so, does XeLaTeX really automatically select optimal optical sizes, and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to what [ChirsS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111117/10102) said relative to `\fontspec`, this has always been the behavior of (La)TeX for as long as I know, i.e. also before `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec`.

You can easily check it yourself. If you compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
{\small      small}\\
{\normalsize normal}\\
{\Large      Large}\\
\end{document}
```

and inspect the fonts used (with `evince` on Linux, simply go "Properties" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>) > "Fonts" tab), you can see that 3 different Type 1C (sub)fonts are embedded in your pdf:

- CMR10,
- CMR12, and
- CMR17

("CMR" stands for "Computer Modern Roman", the default TeX font; the figure is the optical size).

This works whether you compile the document with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: This is not automatic: it's the job of the font definition files to choose optical sizes if available and they must be written out fully.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. As per the manual for the `fontspec` package (section 8.6, 'Optical font sizes'),

> OpenType fonts with optical scaling will exist in several discrete sizes, and these will be selected by XeTeX and LuaTeX *automatically* determined by the current font size...