# Is there a way to use different local font files for different font size in fontspec?

Tags: fontsize, fontspec

I am a big lover of the [EB-Garamond fonts](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) by Georg Duffner. As of now, he has made two sets of font files, EB-Garamond-8 and EB-Garamond-12, respectively for “design size 8pt” and “design size 12pt”. Is there a way to make `fontspec` (and possibly `unicode-math`, too) use EB-Garamond-8 fonts for small sizes e.g. sub/superscripts, footnotes… and EB-Garamond-12 fonts for regular sizes **when using local font files**¹?

If I use only EBGaramond12, the following code works if I put the EBGaramond12-* .otf files in a fonts/ directory sibling to the .tex²

```
\setmainfont[
    Path=fonts/,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    RawFeature={+clig,+dlig,+cv11},]{EBGaramond12}
```

but if I try to adapt it to use the `SizeFeatures` options

```
\setmainfont[
    Path=fonts/,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    RawFeature={+clig,+dlig,+cv11},
    SizeFeatures={
        {Size={-12}, UprightFont=EBGaramond8-Regular, ItalicFont=EBGaramond8-Italic},
        {Size={12-}, UprightFont=EBGaramond12-Regular, ItalicFont=EBGaramond12-Italic, BoldFont=EBGaramond12-Bold}
    }]{EBGaramond12}
```

Then the document won't compile and I get the following error. Using complete names instead of wildcarded ones changes nothing.

```
The key 'fontspec/UprightFont' is unknown and is being ignored.
```

---

¹ It means that using features that automagically select the right *system* fonts is not an option.

² the file structure is

```
.
├── fonts
│   ├── EBGaramond08-Italic.otf
│   ├── EBGaramond08-Regular.otf
│   ├── EBGaramond12-Bold.otf
│   ├── EBGaramond12-Italic.otf
│   └── EBGaramond12-Regular.otf
└── paper.tex
```

Comment: yes, look into the documentation.

Comment: @Herbert Actually using local font files instead of system fonts seems to break the `SizeFeatures` option. Or *vice-versa*.

Comment: There is no need to put the font files into the TeX directory. However, if you are using XeTeX then there will be a problem if you have fonts installed twice, system dir and local tex dir.

Comment: @Herbert I know, but I need to be able to distribute the project to people who might not have EBGaramond installed or not the same version So I need to use a local fonts/ directory

Comment: then define the font by path and filename and extension

Comment: @Hebert Well, that's precisely what I did. And if I try to add `Path=`… in the `{Size }` blocks, I get `The key 'fontspec/Path' is unknown and is being ignored.`

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21297/5763, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111109/5763

Comment: From memory this is a (major) oversight in fontspec which I've been meaning to fix for a long time now… I hope that I can free up some cycles soon to look at it!

Comment: @WillRobertson: If you make that an answer, I'll award the bounty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since version 2.4 of [`fontspec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), it has been possible to use different local fonts for different optical sizes, cf. the [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/README).

The trick is to specify the different fonts with a `Font` option embedded under `SizeFeatures`, which in turn (and this is the crucial part) must be embedded under the options `UprightFeatures`, `ItalicFeatures`, and so on, cf. the [`fontspec manual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) under section `6.6`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{EBGaramond}[
        Path = ./fonts/,
        Extension = .otf,
        UprightFont = *12-Regular, % set EB Garamond 12 as default upright font
        UprightFeatures = {
            SizeFeatures = {
                {Size = -10.1,
                    Font = *08-Regular}, % use EB Garamond 08 for 10pt size and smaller
                {Size = 10.1-}}}, % use default upright font for larger than 10pt size
        ItalicFont = *12-Italic, % set EB Garamond 12 as default italic font
        ItalicFeatures = {
            SizeFeatures = {
                {Size = -10.1,
                    Font = *08-Italic}, % use EB Garamond 08 for 10pt size and smaller
                {Size = 10.1-}}}, % use default italic font for larger than 10pt size
        SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps},
        Ligatures = {Common, TeX},
        Numbers = {Proportional, OldStyle}]
\begin{document}

EB Garamond 08: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1234567890

\textit{EB Garamond 08: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1234567890}

\large
EB Garamond 12: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1234567890

\textit{EB Garamond 12: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1234567890}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7313/30280) for how to use `\large` and variants correctly. Use `{\large ...}` instead of `\large{...}`, as they don't take any arguments; they are switches.

Comment: +1.  You can make the example clearer by removing `SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps}` (unnecessary with EB Garamond), `Ligatures = {Common, TeX}` (on by default), and `Numbers = {Proportional, OldStyle}` (defaults in EB Garamond).

Comment: @Thérèse I included them on purpose to demonstrate that features that apply globally to all the EB Garamond fonts don't need to be specified individually under options like `UprightFeatures` (the manual leads you to believe they do). I can edit my answer and make this explicit.

Comment: For purposes of demonstration, a feature that’s *not* on by default would be better.

Answer (score 10):

If you download the fonts from Georg Duffner’s site, the archive includes a file called `README.xelualatex`. It tells you to load the font with `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}` (not your `\setmainfont{EBGaramond12}`), and explains that the sizes will take care of themselves.  It also explains how to turn off optical sizes if you like: `\setmainfont[OpticalSize=0]{EB Garamond 12 Regular}`.

Comment: In my case (and in @Evpoks, as evidenced by the comment), I have to include the fonts in the distributed content in case the end-user doesn't have them. This means I *have* to reference them by filename, so this is not an option.

Comment: I was just going to suggest using `\directlua{fonts.names.scan(".")}`, but that’s a neat trick which seems not to work any longer since TeX Live 2013.  We need a lua expert to tell us how it goes now.

Comment: The question is clearer now with the footnotes, and I see that my answer doesn’t address your situation. However, I’ll leave the answer here anyway, because anyone who downloads EB Garamond from CTAN and not straight from Georg Duffner’s site is likely to be unaware of his explanations (the CTAN package being directed toward users of pdftex).

Answer (score -1):

I still use the `NFSS` instead of `fontspec`. And `NFSS` has something for font sizes. I never used this feature, therefore can't suggest the exact syntax.

Below is my private NFSS-setup for Univers as an example. It uses the private encoding `EUT1`, you should change it to probably `EU1`.

```
\DeclareFontFamily{EUT1}{univers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EUT1}{univers}{m}{n}{ <-> "[UniversCom-55Roman.ttf]"}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EUT1}{univers}{m}{it}{ <-> "[UniversCom-55Oblique.ttf]"}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EUT1}{univers}{bx}{n}{ <-> "[UniversCom-65Bold.ttf]"}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EUT1}{univers}{bx}{it}{ <-> "[UniversCom-65Bold.ttf]:slant=0.2"}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EUT1}{univers}{bl}{n}{ <-> "[UniversCom-75Black.ttf]"}{}
\DeclareErrorFont{EUT1}{univers}{m}{n}{10}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{EUT1}{univers}{m}{n}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question at all.