# How to choose fonts with different optical sizes with fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontsize, fontspec, ebgaramond

The font [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/design.html) is a font that provides (at the moment two) different optical sizes. The [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package will automatically choose the appropriate optical size (cf. the manual under section 8.6.).

But how can one do this when fonts are explicitly selected with path specifications? In the first MWE below, `fontspec` loads the system font `EB Garamond`, and notice the differences in the fonts in the `tiny` size and the normal size. In the second MWE, `fontspec` loads an explicitly declared font, and in this case, the font is simply scaled down.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
{\tiny{1234567890}}
1234567890
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
    [
        Path = M:/MyStuff/Fonts/EBGaramond-0.015d/otf/,
        UprightFont = EBGaramond12-Regular.otf
    ]
    {EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
{\tiny{1234567890}}
1234567890
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you clarify how this question differs from the problem explored in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114223/7883?

Comment: @Thérèse: It doesn't seem like it does.